Not getting list of subscribers from Paddle
I am not getting the list of subscriptions that I expected based on the Paddle list subscriptions documentation.
Here, there is no required field for query parameters, so if I send {}, then it should return whole list of subscriptions.
Below is my code for getting the list of subscriptions. I had used the Paddle SDK, and created a Paddle Provider. For the particular user's subscription, I passed the customerId also, but it still does not return any data.
const getUserAllSubscription = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userSubscriptions = paddle.subscriptions.list({
            customerId: 'ctm_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        });

        console.log("userSubscriptions >>>>>>", userSubscriptions);
        return res.status(200).send(userSubscriptions);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error from PADDLE > getUserAllSubscription: ${error}`, 'error');
        throw error;
    }

}

Below is the response that I am getting:
userSubscriptions >>>>>> SubscriptionCollection {
  client: Client {
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    options: { environment: 'sandbox', logLevel: 'verbose' },
    baseUrl: 'https://sandbox-api.paddle.com'
  },
  hasMore: true,
  estimatedTotal: 0,
  data: [],
  nextLink: '/subscriptions?customer_id=ctm_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

